# Advanced I/O shifting bits

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register

I wanted to tinker around more with the 8-bit shift register (74HC595) so I tried to make a simple LED display and after reading about some shift commands I got lost and didn't understand much...

Let's start simple...

from what I read -- you can send out Binary data 1s and 0s --- **does the shift regsiter read it as on and off?** the shift register I'm using which is probably the same thing with others but it has 8 pins that can be used as output --- **how does it output the data?** --- does it output (example) 10100110 which shifts to the right as if `00000000 -> 10000000 -> 11000000 -> 01100000 -> 00110000 -> 10011000 -> 0100110 -> 10100110` through the pins one by one? **like pin 1 would get *0* first then *0* will move to pin 2 and pin 1 will get a *1*?** (still using 10100110 by example above ^ )

Also what would the code look like? how does `shiftOut()` and `shiftIn()` work exactly? does all of this have something to do with `pulseIn()`? what do the bitwise operators like `>>` and `<<` or `~` to name a few exactly do?

let's say I made 8 leds hooked up to one of each output pin of the shift-register --- **how do I give data to the register?** what commands should I use to give data? --- from what I understood I can output `01011011` right? if so, **how does the shift-register output it?** and if (Assumingly) it does output it like on and off would it *eventually* turn out as if `LED1 = OFF` `LED2 = ON` `LED3 = OFF` `LED4 = ON` `LED5 = ON` `LED6 = OFF` `LED7 = ON` `LED8 = ON` as if I entered in `01011011`?

***tl;dr***

***how do 8-bit shift registers work and how do you make codes work with them*** xP

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. You should do some research yourself first. Start by reading a [tutorial on the 74HC595 shift register](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-4-eight-leds?view=all): it should answer most of your questions. Then look at the [source code of `shiftOut()`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c#L40). If you still have doubts then, come back here with **more specific** questions.

Comment: I bolded out the questions I'd like answered most although I'd understand if you still find it too broad

Comment: Did you read the tutorial?

Comment: I read another thing about it but it doesn't address above questions or at least I didn't understand those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 74HC595 in combination with the Arduino, the best way to check is to use the default example by Arduino:

[ShiftOut](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut)

With the ShiftOut you can shift the bits into the IC which will make the correct LEDs light up (or not).

Probably you can lit up a LED when passing a HIGH, but you will know very easily by trying the example and check some values/for loops to make them dynamically lighting.

Probably after playing with the example, it will give you much more insight than describing the details here.

Update:

- Try first with 00000000 and 11111111 and 8 leds, so you know if 0 will be OFF and 1 will be ON.
- Than try with eg 10101010 and 8 leds ... than you know if the first or the last will be on or off.
- pulseIn is unrelated
- The operators >> and << are so called bit shift operators. Like 1 << 3 gives 8, the binary value 0000001 is shifted 3 bits left resulting in 00001000 which has value 8.
- ~ is the not operator -> which reverses bits.
- The shiftOut function can be used to send data to the 74HC595N.
- And to be honest, how does it work ... does it really matter for now? First see what the result is, how to use it. Later you can get into details. Start simple first.

Comment: how do I give out 11111111? do I need to make a variable that has 255 to make all bits become 1? or is there another way? --- also the shiftOut works like this "shiftOut(-dataPin-, -clockPin-, MSBFIRST, -variable-)" right? is the dataPin the pin connected to the arduino?

Comment: Yes, 255 is 11111111 binary. You can also use a for loop and set each bit with << operator. Data and clock pin are explained in the example (just connect it to the correct pins of the 74HC595, LSBFIRST/MSBFIRST decide the order, the variable is the 255 number above). The data pin you have to connect to the Arduino, otherwise the 74HC595N cannot receive the value.

Comment: I see, I see --- I will test this out when I get home thanks for the answer :)